# SQL statement conversion to criteria (Hibernate )

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have an SQL query that I would like to convert into a criteria (Hibernate 3.3.2) to use it into my persistancy layer. That's the query :

```
SELECT TYPE_CHANTIER.ID,
  TYPE_CHANTIER.CODE,
  TYPE_CHANTIER.LIBELLE
FROM TYPE_CHANTIER
INNER JOIN CATEGORIE_CHANTIER
ON TYPE_CHANTIER.ID = CATEGORIE_CHANTIER.TYPE
INNER JOIN CHANTIER
ON CATEGORIE_CHANTIER.ID = CHANTIER.CATEGORIE
WHERE CHANTIER.ID = 26869423;
```

I already try a lot a combinations, but there is no result that would be good for me ... This is my code :

```
public TypeChantier recupererTypeChantier(Integer idChantier) {
    TypeChantier retour = null;
    if (idChantier != null) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TypeChantier.class);

        // requete
        criteria.createAlias("categorieChantiers", "categorieChantiers", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
        criteria.createAlias("categorieChantiers.chantiers", "chantiers", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);

        // requete
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("chantiers.id", idChantier));

        // resultat
        retour = (TypeChantier) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
    return retour;
}
```

this code return a java null pointer exception

Comment: At which line do you get the NPE?

Comment: @K.C. retour = (TypeChantier) criteria.uniqueResult();

Comment: Could you post the whole stacktrace please?